Why is this useEffect syntax wrong?
Correct way according to docs is
useEffect(()=>{
  someFunc();
},[])

Wrong way, but why?
useEffect(someFunc,[])

I found this wrong way of using useEffect in our code base but it seems to work just fine, anyone know why it's the wrong syntax?

What makes you think it's wrong?

It may cause issues in the cases where someFunc returns a value that is not callable because React will attempt to run the result of that function as an effect cleanup. If someFunc does not return anything or does actually return its own cleanup code as a function then it's perfectly fine

@jonrsharpe I guess I don't, just the docs I've seen only show using it the long way

It is perfectly valid syntax, in React as in any other JS. As pointed out above there may be semantic issues, things going wrong at runtime due to what (if anything) someFunc returns, but that would depend on the specific implementation.

That short syntax can be used under certain circumstances.
You should just use the long form, until you understand when and why the short form is valid.
The general syntax is just javascript, but to explain that is probably beyond the scope of this question.
The function passed to useEffect needs to meet the requirements. If it does that, then it doesn't matter in which "form" that function is passed (e.g. in that "long form" or "short form")
